# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (5): y

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to run this code but it keeps saying

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (5): y
```

and I have no idea why. I have looked at other questions with similar errors but I still don't get it:

```
flights = read.csv("http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/UG/JM/DATA1001/r/current/projects/2020data/flights.csv")

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

newdata = subset(flights, Year >= 2010)
average_flights = newdata %>%
  filter(Year >= "2010" & Year <= "2021")%>%
  filter(Month_num >= 1 &Month_num !=12) %>%
  group_by(Month_num)%>%
  summarise(sum_flights = sum(All_Flights))

myflights2 = flights %>% 
  filter(Year >= "2010" & Year <= "2021") %>%
  group_by(Airline) %>%
  count() %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  head(5) %>%
  ggplot(myflights2, mapping = aes(x = Airline, y = average_flights, fill(In_Out))) + 
         geom_bar() +
         ggtitle("Average Number of Flights Each Month Per Airline")
ggplotly(myflights2)
```

Comment: Hello annie, could you show a sample of your data to make the helping easier

Comment: As @elielink says, we need to see your data.  But, looking at your code, could it be that you calculate `sum_flights` but ask to plot `average_flights` on the y axis?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work :( because I calculate average_flights and filter it for sum_flights so it's all under average_flights @Limey

Comment: I tried to add a screenshot but it won't let me. Here is a link though http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/UG/JM/DATA1001/r/current/projects/2020data/flights.csv @elielink

Comment: can't open your link @annie

Comment: Is it a public dataset?

Comment: No I don't think so, I don't know how to share it with you :( Do you need it to help ? Should I send you an email of it ? @elielink

Comment: Chat option is available in SO,I just need to figure out how to open it

Comment: Please add the output from `dput(flights)` and `dput(myflights2)` to your post.

Comment: What do you mean? @Limey

Comment: We need to see your data. Using `dput` is the best way to provide it.  Please help us to help you.

Comment: @annie just copy/paste the results of the `dput(flights)` in your question post as @Limey suggested

Comment: Month In_Out Australian_City International_City Airline Route Port_Country Port_Region Service_Country Service_Region Stops All_Flights Max_Seats Year Month_num
37865 I Adelaide Denpasar Garuda Indonesia DPS-ADL-MEL Indonesia SE Asia Indonesia SE Asia 0 13 3809 2003 9
37865 I Adelaide Hong Kong Cathay Pacific Airways HKG-ADL-MEL Hong Kong (SAR) NE Asia Hong Kong (SAR) NE Asia 0 8 2008 2003 9
37865 I Adelaide Kuala Lumpur Malaysia Airlines KUL-ADL Malaysia SE Asia Malaysia SE Asia 0 17 4726 2003 9

Comment: the data is too big but there is a sample

Comment: @annie let's continue this on this SO room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232991/links-room so you can share your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after our discussion here is what you need to do :

```
flights2= flights %>% filter(Year>=2010)
flights2$new= paste(flights2$Year, flights2$Month_num)
e = function(i){
  a = flights2[flights2$In_Out==i,]
  b = lapply(unique(a$Airline), function(j){
    return(c(i,j,mean(table(a[a$Airline==j,new]))))
  })
  return(t(as.data.frame(b)))
}
b = lapply(unique(flights2$In_Out), e)
b = rbind(b[[1]],b[[2]])
b = as.data.frame(b)
d = c()
for(i in unique(b$V2)){
  d = c(d, setNames(sum(as.numeric(b[b$V2==i,"V3"])),i))
}
c= b[b$V2%in% names(sort(d,decreasing = T)[1:5]),]
c$V3=as.numeric(c$V3)
ggplot(c,aes(x=V2,y=V3, fill=V1))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

the output is

[image]